# It's a few weeks off/away

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english, spoken-english

If something is just going to happen,is it common to use "off"?

Like:

> - It's just a few weeks off.( Like something, well anything could be used instead of "it's " ,to mean that thing is just a few weeks away?)
> - The due date is just a few weeks off(away).
> - Exams are just a few weeks off(away.)

So what should be used :off/away?

Comment: The two prepositions are usually equivalent and interchangeable in such contexts. But although I can't think of one offhand, I'm pretty sure there will be at least *some* similar / related contexts where ***off*** either sounds "off" or simply doesn't work at all. So as a learner, you should probably just stick to *using* ***away*** yourself, but be prepared to *encounter* ***off***.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+few+weeks+away%2C+a+few+weeks+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20weeks%20away%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20few%20weeks%20off%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "off" or "away" as an adverb to talk about a distance in time as in the sentences presented.  However, the latter (away) is more common.  A few weeks off = A few weeks away.

August is less than a week off (The Free dictionary).

Summer is only a week off (The free Dictionary).